# Networking issues with WireGuard point-to-site setup

Tags: docker, containers, debian, vpn, wireguard

**GOAL:**

I am trying to set up a split-tunnelled point-to-site WireGuard VPN connection so that I can connect from my local Windows PC client to my remote cloud resources as if though I was on the same network with them.

**NETWORK TOPOLOGY:**

The remote network has 2 servers located in `10.0.0.0/24` subnet. The firewall rule for these 2 servers allows all IPv4 TCP, UDP, and ICMP traffic through if they are coming from `10.0.0.0/24` and `10.0.1.0/24` subnets. Otherwise, it just allows outgoing traffic to the internet and blocks any other incoming traffic. Furthermore, the incoming traffic from the internet to ports `80/tcp` and `51820/udp` of Server 1 are allowed.

Server 1 is the Wireguard VPN server located at `10.0.0.249/24` and Server 2 is a test server located at `10.0.0.248/24`. I can confirm the 2 servers are connected to each other via both `ping` and `netcat`. Both servers are using Debian 12.

**VPN SERVER SETTINGS:**

Server 1 is set up using the following `docker-compose` :

https://github.com/ngoduykhanh/wireguard-ui/raw/master/examples/docker-compose/linuxserver.yml

I use an `nginx` reverse proxy to enable access to the dashboard over the internet using the VPN server's public IP.

Running `docker exec -it wireguard /bin/bash` and then `cat /config/wg0.conf` yields the following:

https://gist.github.com/sepsol/d26eae5da05e646769fb33bc1a9d0d8f

**ISSUE:**

I then load the generated config in my WIreGuard client app and after the connection is successfully "activated", I check my PC's routing table and confirm that for all the connections to the `10.0.0.0/24` subnet, it's going to use the `WireGuard Tunnel` interface. But in the end when I try to `ping` or `netcat` either the Server 1 or 2, I get `Request Timeout`.

**QUESTION:**

Why can't I confirm my connection to the remote servers after my VPN connection is established and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue.

For the record, looking at the wireguard docker-compose example, my issue with wireguard-ui was also fixed by changing my including my wg server interface in my allowed IPs. It was this part specifically that I was missing:

[https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-wireguard?tab=readme-ov-file#:~:text=AND%20the%20ip%20of%20the%20server%27s%20WG%20ip%2C%20such%20as%2010.13.13.1](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-wireguard?tab=readme-ov-file#:%7E:text=AND%20the%20ip%20of%20the%20server%27s%20WG%20ip%2C%20such%20as%2010.13.13.1).